# SUM OVER () with Group by and preceding

Tags: sql, sum, hiveql, window-functions

I have a code that works well - with just the dates by phone usage.

```
select  date,
        data,
        SUM(data) OVER (ORDER BY date asc
                            ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) data_30,
        texts,
        SUM(tests) OVER (ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) text_30,
        voice,
        SUM(voice) OVER (ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) voice_30,
        wifi,
        SUM(wifi) 
                OVER (ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) wifi_30
    FROM Table
```

I am just figuring out how to use sum overs the 30 preceding day, but is it possible at all to include a second variable say, I want to see date, by rate plan for these usages?

Something like

```
select  date,
        plan, b, c, d, 
        data,
        SUM(data) OVER (ORDER BY date asc
                            ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) data_30,
        texts,
        SUM(tests) OVER (ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) text_30,
        voice,
        SUM(voice) OVER (ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) voice_30,
        wifi,
        SUM(wifi) 
                OVER (ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) wifi_30
    FROM Table
    group by date, plan, b, c, d
```

Results of just date

```
date  usage  last30sum
1/1   1       1
1/2   1       2
....
1/20  1       30
```

If I had source data of

```
date line     rateplan        usage  
1/1  phone1   10gbplan        1
1/1  phone2   unlimited       2                
1/2  phone3   10gbplan        1                
....
1/30 phone200 10gbplan        1
```

I want to see sorted out

```
date plan        totalusage   rolling_30
1/2  10gbplan   1            4+ sum(28 days before 1/2)
```

Can you group it by date, unl to get the last 30 days that are unl, a, b, c just means other group bys, could be like by device model, or area.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What is `plan`?  What are `b`, `c`, and `d`?  Why are you aggregating?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, hi again!! I posted examples. :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I believe, I may have solved this with writing examples out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out by adding in partition by

```
select  date,
        plan, b, c, d, 
        data,
        SUM(data) OVER (partition by plan, b, c, d
                        ORDER BY date asc
                            ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) data_30,
        texts,
        SUM(tests) OVER (partition by plan, b, c, d
                ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) text_30,
        voice,
        SUM(voice) OVER (partition by plan, b, c, d
                ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) voice_30,
        wifi,
        SUM(wifi) 
                OVER (partition by plan, b, c, d
                ORDER BY date asc
                ROWS between 30 PRECEDING and current row) wifi_30
    FROM Table
```